# Ng2-Charts Unexpected change chart's color when data is changed

Tags: angular7, ng2-charts

In my project I use `ng2-charts`. All works fine and chart is shown as expected (data, labels, chart's colors), but when data is changed then color of chart become grey by default. May someone help to correct problem with chart's color?

Here is my code:

```
import { ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Color, Label } from 'ng2-charts';
...
export class JuridicalBidPrimaryComponent extends BidComponent {
  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  lineChartLabels: Label[];

  lineChartLegend = true;
  lineChartType = 'line';
  lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)'
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
    }];
  options: any = {
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  }

  constructor(
     ...//inject services
  ) {
    super();

    this.initData();
  };

  initData(): void {
    this.lineChartData = [];
    this.lineChartLabels = [];

    if (this.cabinetId)
      this.getData(this.year);
  }

  getData(year: number) {
    this.isLoading = true;

    var limitPromise = this.juridicalLimitService.getPrimary(this.cabinetId, year).catch(error => {
      this.notificationService.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });

    var analyticsPromise = this.juridicalAnalyticsService.getUsedEnergy(this.cabinetId, year).catch(error => {
      this.notificationService.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });

    forkJoin([limitPromise, analyticsPromise]).subscribe(data => {
      this.limits = data[0];

      this.lineChartLabels = data[1].map(e => e.Period);
      this.lineChartData.push(
        {
          data: data[1].map(e => e.Limit),
          label: 'Bid'
        },
        {
          data: data[1].map(e => e.Used),
          label: 'Used'
        }
      );

      this.isLoading = false;
    }, error => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

```
export abstract class BidComponent {
  cabinetId: number;
  isLoading: boolean = false;

  @Input("periods") periods: BaseDictionary[];
  @Input("cabinetId") set CabinetId(cabinetId: number) {
    this.cabinetId = cabinetId;
    this.initData();
  }

  abstract initData(): void;
}
```

As you can see this component is partial and I use setter to listen of `cabinetId` changes.

Here is html part:

```
...
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="150"
                [options]="options"
                [datasets]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"></canvas>
...
```

And I use this component as:

```
<app-juridical-bid-primary [cabinetId]="cabinetId"></app-juridical-bid-primary>
```

I find similar question [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341990/ng2-chart-why-the-charts-color-change-after-update-data-and-label), but, unfortunately, don't understand answer

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of code testing I find answer. It is needed to correct code from question:

```
...
import * as _ from 'lodash'; //-- useful library

export class JuridicalBidPrimaryComponent extends BidComponent {
    lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
    lineChartLabels: Label[] = [];
    ...
    initData(): void {
       /*this.lineChartData = [];
       this.lineChartLabels = [];*/ //-- this lines is needed to remove

       if (this.cabinetId)
         this.getData(this.year);
     }
     getData(year: number) {
       ...
       forkJoin([limitPromise, analyticsPromise]).subscribe(data => {
          this.limits = data[0];

          this.lineChartLabels.length = 0;
          this.lineChartLabels.push(...data[1].map(e => e.Period));

          if (_.isEmpty(this.lineChartData)) {  
            //-- If data array is empty, then we add data series
            this.lineChartData.push(
              {
                data: data[1].map(e => e.Limit),
                label: 'Замовлені величини'
              },
              {
                data: data[1].map(e => e.Used),
                label: 'Використано'
              }
            );
          } else { 
            //-- If we have already added data series then we only change data in data series
            this.lineChartData[0].data = data[1].map(e => e.Limit);
            this.lineChartData[1].data = data[1].map(e => e.Used);
          }
          this.isLoading = false;
        }, error => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
     }
}
```

As I understand `ng2-charts`, if we clean dataset (`lineChartData`) and add new data then the library understand this as create new series and don't use primary settings for the ones. So we have to use previous created series.

I hope it will be useful for anyone who will have such problem as I have.